# Duplicate string names in strings.xml

Tags: android, build, intellij-idea

We have a shared intellij project that we use to build our android app. One person (out of like 10) recently ran into a build error:

```
android-apt-compiler: [ui] <path>\strings.xml:454: error: Resource entry <name> is already defined.
```

Looking into it, sure enough there are duplicate definitions of the string resource, both in the same strings.xml file. These should be fixed, because that makes no sense at all.

But here's what I don't understand: Everyone else can build just fine, despite the duplicate entries in strings.xml. I assume there is some difference between our global or project settings (despite the project being shared) that I can't see.

Any ideas of where to look? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by downgrading to IntelliJ 13.0.3 and reimporting my project from maven.  YMMV

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into a similar problem today. When one of our devs tried to build a project for the first time the build failed, citing duplicate nodes in strings.xml. Indeed there were duplicates in strings.xml, but this has not been a problem before and everyone else could build the same project with the same strings.xml without a problem.

In our case, the solution was found in the 'Project Structure' settings of the intellij project. Our project references some other 'Android Library' projects but the Developer that couldn't build didn't have the 'library project' checkbox ticked in the relevant module's 'Android' configuration node.  Once this checkbox was ticked the project built successfully, and we confirmed that unchecking the box would make the compile fail.

I can't say why this option would have this effect but in our case that was the solution.

Comment: Changing the Libray Project flag did not work for me